# Merge with more than one statement after WHEN MATCHED

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, merge, sql-update

I'm familiar with oracle's `MERGE` statement which is normally used for UPDATE ELSE INSERT.

My question is, could it be used to update **+ insert to a log table?** 
I want to monitor all the records that had been updated, so I need to save them in a log table. So, instead of selecting from two huge tables again, I want to place another `INSERT` statement inside the `WHEN MATCHED` clause .
So it would be something like:

```
MERGE INTO tableA A
using TableB b
ON (a.Col = b.Col)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A.col2 = b.col2
  INSERT INTO tableA_Log (key,col)
  VALUES (a.Key,b.col2) ;
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to have another query from both tables once again(500mil records and 40mil records).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're better off using ordinary updates and inserts for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No, not possible in a single **MERGE** statement.

From [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606), the definition of **MERGE:**

> Use the MERGE statement to select rows from **one or more sources** for update or insertion **into a table** or view.

That means you could select rows from multiple source tables, but update or insert into only one table at a time ie. the table you want to merge.

You could create an **after update trigger** on the table to insert the rows into your log table when rows are updated in the base table.

Comment: The problem with an after update trigger, is that this is a RETRO fixing on this table, it is beeing update in more then 1 other places, so i need only in this case to insert into log table.. and I don't want to select twice from those big tables,i'll upvote you for the effort but that still isn't what I need:(

Comment: @sagi The only way I can think of is to have a separate INSERT statement in pure SQL. Of course, you could do it in single transaction in PL/SQL, but you need a pure SQL solution.